# <fragment> Pick preview layout from "Fragment Layout" context menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Iam including a map in my app. I am doing something like below:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

But in the graphical layout I get the following error:-

[image]

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: do you include android-support-library-v4 ?

Comment: @ALU0075 yes I did include it

Comment: what about googlePlayServicesLib ? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: @ALU0075 yup have included those as well.. I can run my app. but I cant see anything on the section where the map should be displayed

Comment: actually at that fragment ! , So I think your API key and your keyStore to obfuscate project is not stetted in manifest or Google !

Comment: @ALU0075 can you please elaborate

Comment: just sign your application , http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Comment: @ALU0075 I dont think that is going to help

Comment: It's your problem ! , Even a test project must be sign to access google map :)

Comment: @ALU0075 I would understand if my project didnt run at all. But there is a error in the Layout. So it seems there is something wrong there

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your fragment name.
2. Fragment Layout => select your fragment name.

Good luck. :)